# Flutter Realtime Database now showing any data

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to follow the official Firebase Realtime database documentation by inserting a new record to the database in flutter:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/123");

    await ref.set({
      "name": "John",
      "age": 18,
      "address": {"line1": "100 Mountain View"}
    });
```

With the following code I don't get any error when inserting a new record but I can't view the data via the web. Does this possibility exist?

Answer (score 0):

No. The Firebase Realtime Database usually updates within milliseconds.
However, if you are able to reaccess the data, I would like you to write a bug report here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact